# Identify groups of congruent points

Tags: python, math, distance-matrix

I have two sets of points in lists list1 and list2 given below

```
list1 = [['a',[1.2,3.6,4.5]],['b',[3.2,-5.4,6.6]],['c',[1.1,2.2,9.9]],['d',[5.5,12.5,2.9]],['e',[3.5,6.5,22.9]]]
list2 = [['v',[11.2,3.6,4.5]],['x',[13.2,-5.4,6.6]],['y',[11.1,2.2,9.9]],['z',[15.5,12.5,2.9]]]
```

If all the points in list1 are rotated and/or translated, points a, b, c and d align with points v, x, y and z respectively. Currently I have written Python code that can output the groups of pairs provided two input lists using a pairwise distance comparison method. It computes intralist combinatorial distances within list1 and list2 and compares these distances between the lists to identify the pairs. For eg. distance(ab) ~= distance(vx), distance(ac) ~= distance(vy) and so on. The code is given below. My code works but is slow for larger lists. I would like to know if there is any faster or easier way to solve this problem.

Thanks

```
def calculate_distance(point1,point2):
        #function calculates distance
        dis = 0
        dis += math.pow((point2[0]-point1[0]),2)
        dis += math.pow((point2[1]-point1[1]),2)
        dis += math.pow((point2[2]-point1[2]),2)
        distance = math.sqrt(dis)
        return distance

def make_masterdict(list1,list2):
        # calculate interalist combinitorial pairs of points with
        # their distances and store into dicts
        list1pairs = {}
        list2pairs = {}
        for i in range(len(list1)):
                p1 = list1[i][1]
                for p2 in list1[i:]:
                    if list1[i][0] != p2[0]:
                        dist = calculate_distance(p1,p2[1])
                        #store both the pairs in the dictionary
                        list1pairs.update({list1[i][0]+'_'+p2[0]:dist})
                        list1pairs.update({p2[0]+'_'+list1[i][0]:dist})


        for i in range(len(list2)):
                p1 = list2[i][1]
                for p2 in list2[i:]:
                    if list2[i][0] != p2[0]:
                        dist = calculate_distance(p1,p2[1])
                        list2pairs.update({list2[i][0]+'_'+p2[0]:dist})
                        list2pairs.update({p2[0]+'_'+list2[i][0]:dist})

        # calculate interlist pairs between list1 and list2
        masterlist = []
        for i in list1:
                for j in list2:
                        masterlist.append([i[0],j[0]])

        masterdict = {}
        # for each combinatorial pair in masterlist
        for i in range(len(masterlist)-1):
                c1 = masterlist[i]
                key1 = c1[0]+'_'+c1[1]
                masterdict.update({key1:[]})
                for j in range(i+1,len(masterlist)):
                        c2 = masterlist[j]
                        # if the same point is not repeated in the pairs
                        if c1[0] != c2[0] and c1[1] != c2[1]:
                                #collect and compare the distances
                                p1 = c1[0]+'_'+c2[0]
                                p2 = c1[1]+'_'+c2[1]
                                dis1 = list1pairs[p1]
                                dis2 = list2pairs[p2]
                                if abs(dis1-dis2) < 0.1:
                                        #if same distance, then store in masterdict
                                        key2 = c2[0]+'_'+c2[1]
                                        masterdict[key1].append(key2)
        return masterdict                               

def recursive_finder(p1,list1,masterdict,d,ans):
        # if lenght of d is more than 2, store that list in ans
        if len(d) > 2:
                ans.append(d)

        # if lenght of list is 0, do not do anything
        if len(list1) == 0:
                pass
        else:
                other = []
                nextlist = []
                #loop through each value in list1 as p1
                for i in list1:
                        if i in masterdict[p1]:
                                #make empty list
                                newl = []
                                #store old group in newl
                                newl.extend(d)
                                #add new member to old group
                                newl.append(i)
                                #store this list
                                other.append(newl)
                                #store new member
                                nextlist.append(i)
                #repeat for each successful value in nextlist                
                for i in range(len(nextlist)):
                        #collect p1 and dnew 
                        p1 = nextlist[i]
                        dnew = other[i]
                        #repeat process
                        recursive_finder(p1,nextlist[i+1:],masterdict,dnew,ans)

def find_groups(list1,list2):
        #make master dictionary from input lists
        masterdict = make_masterdict(list1,list2)
        ans = []
        #use recursive function to identify groups
        for mainkey in masterdict:
                if len(masterdict[mainkey]) > 1:
                        for i in range(len(masterdict[mainkey])):
                                p1 = masterdict[mainkey][i]
                                recursive_finder(p1,masterdict[mainkey][i+1:],masterdict,[mainkey,p1],ans)

        return ans

#define two lists with a,b,c and d matching v,x,y, and z respectively
list1 = [['a',[1.2,3.6,4.5]],['b',[3.2,-5.4,6.6]],['c',[1.1,2.2,9.9]],['d',[5.5,12.5,2.9]],['e',[3.5,6.5,22.9]]]
list2 = [['v',[11.2,3.6,4.5]],['x',[13.2,-5.4,6.6]],['y',[11.1,2.2,9.9]],['z',[15.5,12.5,2.9]]]
answer = find_groups(list1,list2)
print(answer)
```

Upon running the code, the correct answer is output. Groups larger than size of 3 are output.

```
[['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y'], ['a_v', 'b_x', 'c_y', 'd_z'], ['a_v', 'b_x', 'd_z'], ['a_v', 'c_y', 'd_z'], ['b_x', 'c_y', 'd_z']]
```

Comment: This is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does it check for flips?

Comment: I can’t think of anything too good, but make sure your code gets rid of things that don’t work early on. Makes me think getting all the angles between every two points and comparing the angles and eliminating the points with no common angle would be a good place to start. Obviously through the angle calculation you will have calculated distance, so keep those calculations. Will think more on it.

Comment: For quadrilaterals and above I guess angle and length are not enough